# Assets dont update - Play! 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, refresh, template-engine, assets

I am having trouble doing a Hello World application, and I tried to play with the CSS a bit, and it does not work, it wont update, I have no idea why.
CSS isnt even included in the html when I view the source from browser (Chrome) in the dev console

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

and actually when I right-click, the whole  and  part is ommited like this

```
<h1>My Blog</h1>
<ul>

    <li>
        <h2>
            <a href="/posts/1" >Post #1</a>
        </h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis a pulvinar massa. Nullam gravida rhoncus quam non aliquam. Donec vitae orci at nibh scelerisque.</p>

    </li>   


    <li>
        <h2>
            <a href="/posts/2" >Post #2</a>
        </h2>
        <p>Suspendisse leo ante, ornare et ultrices nec, commodo vitae neque. Proin dictum diam quis nibh elementum et consequat ipsum aliquam. Vestibulum ante ipsum.</p>

    </li>   

</ul>     

<form action="/posts/create" method="POST" >

    <input type="text" name="title" /> </br>
    <input type="text" name="content" /> </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />

</form>
```

main.css

```
p {
    background-color: #FFAABB;
}
```

main.scala.html

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

I am stuck at this and I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you call @main("some title"){ here are your contents} in the template that you call in your controller? Can you please post your template (maybe index.scala.html)?

Comment: You were right, I just deleted that part, I am new to Play! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fantastic. I wrote an answer so you can mark your problem as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer:
Missed to call @main("some title"){ here are your contents} in the page template.